# nopCommerce as Payment Processing Service?

Tags: asp.net, payment-processing, nopcommerce

I am part of a group looking to create a third party payment processor similar to Google Checkout or PayPal (which would require a Merchant Account and integration with a Payment Gateway). I wanted to know whether there are any e-commerce solutions available that would assist in this process, like [Alstrasoft's EPay Enterprise](http://www.alstrasoft.com/epay_enterprise.htm).

We are hesitant to go with Alstrasoft's product due to the lack of reviews, and we are particularly leaning towards ASP.NET so we are wondering if something like [nopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com) could be tweaked into a payment processing service such as described above?

Alternatively, if nopCommerce cannot be tweaked into what we need, does anyone have any suggestions for .NET or another language/framework (whether a complete solution or tools that would help in building what we need)?  We would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

NopCommerce as their site states "designed to help you launch powerful e-commerce solutions" and "is a fully customizable shopping cart".

I'm not sure what you're after to, create an ecommerce or payment gateway, but if its an ecommerce its a really nice project, extensible, also there are some extensions and payment gateways available as plugins.

I think its better if you check out their website specially the [overview](http://www.nopcommerce.com/productinfo.aspx), [features](http://www.nopcommerce.com/featurelist.aspx) to see if it fits your needs, also take a look at their source code as its open.